# Delete an application setting entry

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am able to create new application settings at runtime using this code :

```
SettingsProperty property = new SettingsProperty(sthing);
property.DefaultValue = "Default";
property.IsReadOnly = false;
property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
property.Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new 
System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
Properties.Settings.Default[sthing] = sthing;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Is there something similar to delete a setting at runtime ?
Something like :

```
Properties.Settings.Default["sthing"].Delete
```

Just to clarify : i don't want to clear the value of `sthing` but i want to remove the entry named `sthing`

I am using Winforms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Remove(sthing);
```

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.settingspropertycollection?view=netframework-4.8) what you can do with `Properties.Settings.Default.Properties`.